# Knockout.js Apply Bindings Without Rerendering

Tags: data-binding, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, model-binding

I'm wondering if there's a way to apply binding to some DOM elements without re-rendering the DOM elements.

I ask because in my situation, the server is returning me the HTML build with Razor templates. So the backend handles all the DOM building.

All I want to do is take a fully rendered markup and apply some sort of binding to it, using a robust JS library such as Knockout.js. Is this at all possible.

So for example in normal client side built markup I would do something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: fruits">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

Then apply bindings and built html.

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

Which will result in something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: fruits">
    <li data-bind="text: name">Apples</li>
    <li data-bind="text: name">Pairs</li>
    <li data-bind="text: name">Banana</li>
    <li data-bind="text: name">Peaches</li>
    <li data-bind="text: name">Grapes</li>
</ul>
```

But using Razor templates the HTML is returned like this already but I still want to apply bindings. How do I do this without re-rendering the html. The only other way I can think of is too build my own custom bindings but I want to avoid that.

Is there another framework I could use that does just this? I heard backbone could possibly do this.

Comment: If the server has already returned the html you need, why do you need to bind anything? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Because I want to manipulate the model. Say I have a button that can add a fruit to the model array I want that to be reflected in the DOM through some sort of binding. So server does return the HTML I need but then I might need to change it further.

Comment: A more realistic use case would be for some sort history widget that will persist throughout the entire site but update as the user interacts and adds to the history.

Comment: So what's wrong with just letting Knockout rebuild the DOM?

Comment: I'm actually fine with letting Knockout rebuild the DOM but I want the fully rendered HTML there for SEO purposes. If my markup isn't there on load it won't get sifted by the SEO.

Comment: Well, you could just have the server push the HTML and then have knockout replace it. It'll be seen by web crawlers and, as a bonus, if somebody happens to be browsing with JavaScript turn off, it'll degrade gracefully.

Comment: Matt, yeah that makes sense. What we ended up doing was deferring ko.applyBindings until the user interacts with the view. This will help with performance especially when there is a potential for lots of widgets on a page, and I don't want to apply binding on load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some of the other respondents have said, I think you're better off doing this a different way. IF you'd rather avoid the additional server round trip of an Ajax call to get the data, you could get the server to render a JSON string representing your data, and embed that in your HTML alongside the HTML template.

You could then use JSON.parse to parse this string into a JSON tree and bind those values into your view model in the view model's constructor.

That way you'll get the performance boost of returning the data from the server as part of the response, but without bending Knockout out of shape. As an added bonus, adding AJAX behaviour to e.g. Update this data becomes much easier.

Comment: What I'm asking my back-end devs to do is to return me the HTML markup as well as a script block containing a representation of my C# model in JSON. Then that JSON gets used by Knockout. That way I can manipulate my model.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are mixing approaches and this will end up a bit of a mess.  With that said, if you *really* want to do this to simplify DHTML, etc, then I'd recommend you not try to fudge foreach bindings into provided markup in this, and have your model reflect the server-side provided model.  Rough example:

```
var model = {
   fruits: {
      apple: { name: ko.observable('Apples') },
      pairs: { name: ko.observable('Pairs') },
      banana: { name: ko.observable('Banana') },
      peaches: { name: ko.observable('Peaches') },
      grapes: { name: ko.observable('Grapes') },
   }
}

<ul data-bind="with: fruits">
    <li data-bind="text: apple.name">Apples</li>
    <li data-bind="text: pairs.name">Pairs</li>
    <li data-bind="text: banana.name">Banana</li>
    <li data-bind="text: peaches.name">Peaches</li>
    <li data-bind="text: grapes.name">Grapes</li>
</ul>
```

It's ugly because it is :-)  Best answer is to please consider a different approach.

Comment: The main for having all the HTML rendered server-side is for SEO purposes. I can easily erase some DOM elements via jQuery then repopulate it with Knockout.